# Using Database entries to dynamically create a visio diagram

Tags: sql, database, diagram, visio, flowchart

Is this possible?

We have a Configuration Management Database that stores information such as our servers, what datacentre they're stored in, applications that reside on them, as well as interfaces that send data from one application to another.

We would like to use Visio to connect to our SQL 2005 database, and automatically generate  a flow diagram that details these dependancies and relationships.

So again - is this possible?  If so, does anyone know of some documentation that details how to do this?

Comment: Perhaps it would be useful to post the relevant parts of the database schema?

Answer (score 5):

Is **[this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb267248.aspx)** what you are looking out for?

Comment: not really... it's too 'general'.  I can't make it work for some reason.  perhaps I'm missing an important piece of info?